# Why is my buck regulator based on LM22679 limiting current way under the set limit?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, switching-regulator

I have a LM22679-ADJ based buck converter. The output voltage is set to 24V. The input voltage may vary from 28-40V DC. The current limit is set to above 5A according to the graph given in the datasheet. Here's the schematic:
[image]

*The values of R1,R2,R3,R4 were incorrect. Actual values used were 47k,47k,5.1k,1.8k.
The R7 resistor is set to 6.8k to set load limit at just above 5A. And one of the inductors is shorted. Diodes used were Schottky type as advised in the datasheet.

Significant observations:

1. With a load of 25 ohms the waveform across D1 becomes distorted, and the device starts limiting current, when measured across the diode D1 only when the input voltage is above 31V.
2. When I add another inductor in parallel to the one in the circuit thereby reducing the inductance to ~2.3uH, the input voltage at which the output voltage drops out of regulation increases, however, it is not completely gone.

The following are the images of the DSO under different circumstances, all measured across the diode D1 and load resistance fixed at 25 ohms.

Case 1: Inductance 4.7uH. The max input voltage at which output is not distorted(~31V). Output voltage is regulated and current is not limited. This is whats supposed to happen.
[image]

Case 2: Inductance 4.7uH. But input voltage increased to 35V. Although output voltage is very close to set voltage, the waveform doesn't make sense. What is supposed to happen is the square wave is supposed to reduce its duty cycle. But this happens instead.
[image]

Case 3: Inductance halved to 2.3uH. Input voltage at 35V. Note the change in waveform. The output voltage is still being regulated at 24V.
[image]

Case 4: Inductance 4.7uH. Input voltage increased further to 37.5V. The output voltage completely drops out of regulation to about 17V. To reset the IC from this state, either the load must be removed or it must be reset at lower input voltage. Simply reducing the input voltage to where it previously used to regulate output does not make the IC regulate output again. There is a hysteresis of some sort.
[image]

Case 5: Inductance halved to 2.3uH and input voltage at 37.5V. This time, the output does not drop out of regulation. But the waveform is still weird.
[image]

I have calculated the output inductor value as per the datasheet and it came out to be 9.6uH for max input of 40V and output of 24V. But, with both inductors in series, the output dropped out of regulation much sooner than in the above mentioned cases.
[This is the datasheet.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm22679-q1.pdf?ts=1599714933439&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Questions:

1. Why is the wave form like this and not a square wave like the first case at higher input voltages? (and what is the role of the output inductor in this)
2. What can I do do that my regulator does not drop out of regulation for the max input of 40V?

Thank You.

EDIT:
@csabahu I had the chance to take some measurements today.

At 10uH,200uF,25Ω the IC drops out of regulation at input of 32.2V

At 4.7uH,200uF,25Ω the IC drops out of regulation at input of 36.2V

At 2.3uH,200uF,25Ω the IC drops out of regulation didn't drop out of regulation for 40V. But I tried a load of 16.7Ω and it certainly did drop out of regulation.

Halving output capacitor value had no significant effect on above measurements.

I also tried increasing the inductance value to about 24uH. At 100uF and 25Ω there was no dropping out of regulation. Further, the ringing due to what I'd presume was discontinuous mode operation was completely gone even at 40V.(Which is to be expected I suppose) This also holds for 16uH at similar conditions. However, at increasing the load to 16.7Ω the IC immediately goes into current limit. What was interesting to note here was that the IC seemed like it was skipping cycles. And the waveform did not resemble the DCM operation. The frequency was lower than the standard 500Khz.

I removed the 6.8k R7 current limit resistor, but this had no effect on any of the above measurements.

Comment: `all measured across the diode D1` the oscillograms show no problems as they are all expected waveforms. They don't indicate any distortion of the output voltage. You should measure the voltage across C9 like shown [here](https://www.eetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/media-1055304-figure-2.jpg).

Comment: @Rohat could you explain why the waveform must contain this oscillation instead of it just being a square wave with different duty cycles for different input voltages?

Comment: You should google buck converter waveforms and understand that as the inductor's energy depletes cyclically you will get a sine wave content due to MOSFET output capacitance. By the way, posting a circuit and then amending the values in text is really annoying; post the correct circuit and provide links to the chip and the inductor.

Comment: @Andyaka Are you talking about ringing? If so, take a look once more at my images. The switch on rising edge is lower than than the input voltage. If you were to take the mean of the oscillations, or extrapolate the oscillations until the damping is finished you will see that the voltage is lesser than the applied voltage. Moreover, the ringing is usually damps out, but in this case, the oscillations stop abruptly mid wave and then it resumes with the square wave. Also, note that Coss of low side FETs cause ringing in traditional synchronous buck converters, but I have used Schottky diodes.

Comment: I have no idea where you are going with this. Go study this effect or raise a specific new question about it - this cannot be simply explained in comments.

Comment: @Andyaka What? Read my question again. This is exactly what I asked! (I explicitly titled a section for questions. Read the first number in it.) Why would I write a new question?

Comment: Those waveforms are across D2 and not on the output (C9) so if you have output waveform distortions (C9 is the output) and, you think the waveforms you show in your picture are across C9, then you are either mistaken or there's something really wrong with your circuit (or maybe C8, C9, C10 isn't fitted correctly).

Comment: Oh, so that's where the misunderstanding stems from. I have corrected my statement. My question was regarding the waveforms across D1 and not the 'output waveform' of the buck converter.

Comment: @underdog As stated before, there's nothing unexpected with the waveforms. If you really interested in these waveforms then you should study buck converters from readily-available online resources. Regarding your main problem, I suggest you visit TI Webench to obtain a reference design and to verify yours. NOTE: When I checked from TI Webench the design tool didn't allow me to select min. input voltage as 28VDC. Besides, the recommended inductor value was 18uH. So, maybe you should increase the inductance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP needs to study basic buck converter waveforms to realize that what is seen is pretty normal.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Increasing inductance leads the IC to drop out of regulation even sooner as I vary the input voltage over its range.I checked Webench too. It seems it keeps some margin as the max duty of the IC is 90%. That's why it won't select 28VDC as a viable input.

Comment: @Andyaka If it's so basic then explain it. The explanation is part of answering the question. Handwaving the question away because it happens a lot seems questionable to me.(nor does it take away from the validity of the question) If you don't have the time to explain then leave. No one is forcing you to answer.

Comment: 3rd comment from the top I gave an explanation. You should really study why this happens but it's beyond explaining this in a comment and given that you made such an error from the start in what you called the output (misleading folk along the way despite the top comment from Rohat explaining this), you should delete and start over with a new question on the sine wave subject. However, if you searched this site I've seen that Q and A already. Also, don't be so bloody rude - leave that to the guys who know their stuff!!

Comment: [LINK](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=buck+converter+ringing)

Comment: @Andyaka I apologize for being rude. Appreciate the info. The reason I included the sine wave stuff in my question is because I thought it had something to do with my regulator going in to current limit way under the limit(which is main title). But, it doesn't, it seems. But, I couldn't have known that a priori.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the simulation, I would have three suggestions for a likely solution to the problem.
Basically, the source of the problem is overcurrent protection and the output capacitor.
Here, two things can cause overcurrent, one is a poorly chosen (small) inductance, and the other is a capacitor that is too large at the output.
I took the value of the SS capacitor smaller than the original to keep the simulation for a normal period of time.

1. **Inductance**

With an inductance of 4.7uH or less, the peak current exceeds 7.1A (5A load) and the system becomes unstable.
[image: nulla]

Thus, the value of the inductance returns to the calculated **10uH**.
[image: egy]

2. **Current limit**

The set current limit 5A is removed (6.8k) because the output current 5A has a higher switching (inductance) current.
This retains the built-in 7.1A current limit. This will be just enough for the 5A output current.
There should be no resistance at all, but the model doesn’t like that state, so it will be 5k at the limiting input (for the model only).
[image: kettő]

The 5A load is OK, now let's look at the 25 Ohm load with which the measurements were made (28V and 40V inputs).
[image: három]

[image: négy]

[image: öt]

Apparently everything works except that I use a 100 uF capacitor on the output instead of 200uF.

3. **Output capacitor**

200uF at 500kHz is completely unnecessary, 100uF is enough, only a capacitor with a small ESR value is needed (electrolyte plus ceramic).
A large output capacitor with a large time constant degrades the stability of the system.

[image: kondi]

Unfortunately, several hours are not enough to model the phenomenon with a large capacitor.
So this part is not exact, just a conclusion.
Due to the large output capacitor, each switch-on activates the internal overcurrent protection beyond the SS timing.
This puts you in a state where you can only get out when you are turned off.
So we can't turn it on. We see this on the oscilloscope. It also switches off at the moment of switching on, so the signal oscillates.
It then switches to a lower frequency as if there is a short circuit at its output.
The phenomenon is described in the data sheet.

> Therefore, even if the
> load is shorted with zero volts across its terminals, the inductor will still see a finite voltage. It is this value that
> should be used for V x and V sc in the calculations. In order to return from foldback mode, the load must be
> reduced to a value much lower than that required to initiate foldback. This load "hysteresis" is a normal aspect of
> any type of current limit foldback associated with voltage regulators.

So what will hopefully help is 10uH inductance, no special current limit and the output capacitor is only 100uF.

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer. I will try playing with the output capacitor values when I get to work in a while. Just one thing though, I don't know if it's a typo but you seem to have written 2000uF where it should have been 200uF as in the schematic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw 100 as 1000 ... This makes the situation better.
The ceramic, on the other hand, is too small to have a small ESR. What might even be interesting is that there is a piece of inductance so that they can't interact.

Comment: Can you simulate the circuit in DCM mode?

Comment: I wanted to, but the model doesn't want to. :) The current of inductance is continuous even at low loads.

Comment: I took some measurements today. Please see edit.

Comment: All indications are that it limits at a much lower current than would be normal. Missed cycles and lower frequency are also signs of this. Somewhere around 2A peak current starts to restrict. I assume the inductance resistance is small and the saturation current is greater than 7A. There are many others left, maybe you could try to take a series resistor with a 10nF capacitor. Maybe the opening voltage of the gate with the resistance is small. I'm trying a simulation with series resistance, I haven't done it yet. We need to find out where the extra current will be ...

Comment: I found something else with a longer simulation. The system is [not stable](https://imgur.com/a/sva8dKq), this is not visible in the magnified details. It appears to be stabilizable (1.5nF) by compensating for the [feedback](https://imgur.com/a/p66hY9C). You have to try this because it’s just a [model](https://imgur.com/a/22tKd3i), not reality. The value of the capacitor can be somewhere between 1nF and 5nF. You should still read [this](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management/f/196/t/728185) because you have a very similar problem.

Comment: @csabahu I tried your recommendation of adding 1nF at R1. And it seems to work for higher loads. I increased my load to about 2.4A and it still regulates. However, at low loads the output seems to be unstable and and fluctuating  a little. (~0.1-0.2V).what I mean by instability is that each cycle is not the same. The dcm oscillations stop at different points in the wave. However output seems to be regulated throughout. I'll play around with the inductor values and edit my post after a while.

Comment: I haven’t even noticed this so far, but take C1 off R3 because it also degrades stability. Unfortunately, I can't model the DCM mode because the model doesn't work if the inductor current drops to zero. I think these circuits are compensated for low output voltages (3-5V) internally, so we should try external compensation at 24V output.